# TortoiseHg with TortoiseSvn Diff

Tags: tortoisesvn, diff, tortoisehg

I recently switched over from SVN to Hg. I used to use TortoiseSVN, and now I'm using TortoiseHg. One thing I really miss, though, are the TortoiseSVN style diffs; the Hg ones are just harder to read and understand.

Is there some way to tell TortoiseHg to use the TortoiseSVN diff tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right Click -> TortoiseHg -> Global Settings -> TortoiseHg -> Visual Diff tool -> Choose TortoiseMerge

Comment: What if TortoiseMerge is not listed under Visual Diff Tools?

Comment: @ashes999 - it should be there if TortoiseSVN ( or TortoiseGit ) is installed

Comment: that's what I expected too. Very strange.

Comment: question asks for **TortoiseDiff**, answer gives **TortoiseMerge**. Very different tools. The second doesn't show diff on image files. From [all I can say](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/tortoiseidiff-tortoisehg), the first can't be set that easily.

Comment: For some reason this is not happening on my Windows 8.1 machine, anyone an idea why?

Answer (score 4):

No idea why *TortoiseHg* doesn't come with this built in, because both [*TortoiseSVN*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/Tools/1.6.7/TortoiseDiff-1.6.7.zip/download) and *TortoiseGIT* do.

So we have to somehow download `TortoiseIDiff.exe` from either project, add it to our *TortoiseHg folder* and add **something** along those lines into `Mercurial.ini`, which currently can be found under **Windows Explorer's contextual menu (right mouse click) > TortoiseHg > Global Settings > Edit File**:

```
[extdiff]
cmd.tortoisediff = C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoiseIDiff.exe
opts.tortoisediff = /left:"$parent" /lefttitle:"$plabel1" /right:"$child" /righttitle:"$clabel" /showinfo
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick, but I also had to copy the DLLs from TortoiseSVN in hg folder.  Works with both tortoiseMerge and tortoiseIdiff.  Note that tortoiseMerge parameters are not the same (and dont seem necessary for the diff to work)

Comment: I copied the TortoiseIDiff.exe with all other dlls to TortoiseHg folder (along thg.exe), setup the settings like cregox described and still doesn't work. The TortoiseIDiff window doesn't appear, there's nothing happening when I try to diff any two files. Wheareas if I change the vdiff tool to any other, it works! Grrr, this is very frustrating. Seems something is blocking the TortoiseIDiff tool from being run. I have newest TortoiseHg x64 and Win 7 x64. Any ideas what else to try?

Comment: @Koshmaar it has been at least 2 years I don't touch a windows machine of my own so I've got little clues on what you could try, but... if you seem to be the only one complaining (on the web) then there's probably something wrong in your setup. so, the only advice I can give you right now is to **double check every single thing** - it could be a missing character on the settings or some conflicting tool you've got installed, among so many details that could go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Put following into Mercurial.ini:

```
[tortoisehg]
vdiff = tortoisediff

[extdiff]
cmd.tortoisediff = C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseMerge.exe
opts.tortoisediff = /base:"$parent" /basename:"$plabel1" /theirs:"$child" /theirsname:"$clabel"
```